# Ubuntu, screen lock without screensaver

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, screensaver, lock-screen, ubuntu-18.04

When I do not use my graphical session anymore, the screensaver automatically lock it and power off the screen to save energy.

I want it to keep locking my session but not to power off the screen, is it possible ?

I use Ubuntu 18.04 with default gnome display manager.

Thank you,

Matias

Comment: You should be able to control whether the screen powers off in the power control settings.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that if I lock the screen and then *immediately* move the mouse around then the screen does not power off. I am also using Ubuntu 18.04 with the default gnome display manager.

(You may also want to set Power > Power Saving > Blank Screen to Never)

Comment: Are you referring to manually locking the screen rather than using a screensaver?

Comment: Yes, just locking the screen manually and not using a screensaver at all.

Comment: I chuckled when I saw this answer. Now I'm upvoting it because this is *literally* the only solution that worked for me. Thanks! @Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Just press `Super` + `L` for a bit longer.

This worked for me on desktop with Ubuntu 20.

Answer (score -2):

You can disable the power-saving feature.  You can find that somewhere in Settings.  That will keep your screen from turning off.

And as for locking your screen in a console environment, you can use something like 'vlock'. You should be able to find that program in the repos.

This will work if I understand what you're trying to do correctly.

Comment: "Somewhere in Settings" isn't really an answer. I've spent time looking and haven't found it, which is why I'm on SU reading this.